# Running gradlew lint on specific file(s)

Tags: git, android-studio, gradle, gradlew, android-lint

I'm trying to create pre-commit hook with code style check and other errors. It's a multi-module project in Android Studio (java and kotlin).
I was hoping to use **lint**, but no luck.

My condition is to check only new and modified files (baseline is in order ofc) as the project is way too big to run checks on every commit on every file.

My **sh** command looks like this:

```
git diff --name-only HEAD | xargs -I '{}' ./gradlew lint {}\;
```

It translates to:

```
./gradlew lint /path/to/the/file.java
```

But it always fails on trying to find task called "the path to the file".

When I try to use **lint** from **Android SDK** it just prints `main: Error: "main" is a Gradle project. To correctly analyze Gradle projects, you should run "gradlew :lint" instead.`

Any advice?

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot pass arguments to the Android Lint tool (except `android.lintOptions`).
Also I don't think that running lint over specific files is a good idea: often we declare XML resources and later use them from Java/Kotlin code - this way you lose some important lint features (like unused resources), which require to analyze multiple scopes and files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/lint for specific files

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).